# Disable switching between different desktops with mouse scroll

Tags: dock, scrolling, 22.04, multiple-desktops

I just upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04 and so far I am loving the new update.

After changing the dock to auto hide I found that when you move your mouse to the left side of the screen and scroll it switches between different desktops. All though this is a nice addition it does not work well with auto-hide dock. Especially when there is a lot of apps on the dock and I have to scroll down to access them I always accidentally move my mouse close to the edge and then instead of scrolling the dock I scroll to a different desktop.

You can already change to next desktop quickly by going to activities overview and scrolling so is there anyway to disable the scroll between desktops at the left side of the screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As vanadium put in [his answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404408/1188091), the extension setting is not exposed in UI. But you can install [dconf-editor](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/dconf-editor.1.html) and change the `scroll-option` to `do-nothing` setting under the `dash-to-dock` extension.

Or you can change in command line itself by,

```shell
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock scroll-action 'do-nothing'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 22.04

Right click to the Desktop -> "Configure Desktop and Wallpaper..." -> "Mouse Actions" -> Here remove "Vertical-Scroll" action for "Switch Desktop"