# How can I disable switching between different 'WORKSPACES' by scrolling mouse wheel over the dock?

Tags: gnome, mouse, 22.04, workspaces, dock

I want to *disable* switching between different *Workspaces* by scrolling the mouse wheel when the pointer is over the dock of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I tried the following solutions:

[solution_1](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404408/1592648)

[solution_2](https://askubuntu.com/a/1130184/1592648)

[solution_3](https://superuser.com/a/1635268/1719138)

but none of them worked. I also tried downloading *gnome extension manager* and searching for the relevant extensions but couldn't find one.

***System: Ubuntu 22.04, Linux Kernel version 5.15.0-30-generic, GNOME Shell version 42.0***

Comment: Gnome4 won't let you do it. It always creates one more workspace than you've occupied.

Comment: @kanehekili, I want to use multiple workspaces but don't want to switch between them by scrolling the mouse wheel.

Comment: Same. Florian Müllner (which is one of the few gnome developers that really supports users) mentions it [here](https://discourse.gnome.org/t/how-to-disable-super-mousewheel-switching-workspaces/8109). The gist is to write your own addon.

Comment: The link in your first solution worked immediately for me on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable switching between different desktops with mouse scroll](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404348/disable-switching-between-different-desktops-with-mouse-scroll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially the [solution_1](https://askubuntu.com/a/1424791/1592648) mentioned in my question was not working when I posted this question. But for some reason now it's working.

You have to do the following as mentioned in solution_1:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock scroll-action 'do-nothing'
```